# How to bind an observable objects published integer variable to a textField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, formatter, observableobject

I have a viewmodel class like so:

```
class SharedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objectHeight: Int? = nil
}
```

and I am trying to bind to bind the variable to a textfield with a number formatter like so (the variable needs to be used throughout so in the current view the viewmodel is an `@EnvironmentObject`):

```
TextField("Height", value: $sharedViewModel.$objectHeight, formatter: NumberFormatter()
```

But I get this error when I hit the enter key in the simulator: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fd9d6830fa8) to 'Combine.Published<Swift.Optional<Swift.Int>>.Publisher' (0x7fd9d5197d10).

Edit: Using an optional Int as just a state variable works fine it is the Published tag while using an Observable object as an EnvironmentObject that seems to be causing the issue. However, I need this variable inside the EnvironmentObject as it is used in multiple views.

Comment: What if the Published Int is _not_ an Optional?

Comment: Same result unfortunately, also tried using a double instead of an int I think it is to do with the Published tag but not entirely sure, as I am using a published String value in a Picker and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it non-optional and remove the `$` before `$objectHeight`. Only leave the ViewModel one

```
$sharedViewModel.objectHeight
```

Comment: Don't actually need to make it non-optional but the extra "$" was what was causing the issue. Thank you 